# How to change the widget state value when another state value changed

Tags: flutter, widget, dropdown

I want to change the flutter `switch` value when the dropdown value changes. The `switch` is Stateful widget, for example, the dropdown value is changed to `1` to `4` if the dropdown value is 4 then the called switch value should change.

**That is my need**

[image]

The switch is custom widget

**My Switch Widget**

```
class SwitchField extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchField(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.value,
      required this.callback});
  final String title;
  final bool value;
  final Function callback;

  @override
  State<SwitchField> createState() => _SwitchFieldState();
}

class _SwitchFieldState extends State<SwitchField>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late String title = widget.title;
  late bool value = widget.value;
  late Function callback = widget.callback;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 50,
      child: ListTile(
          title: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
          trailing: SizedBox(
            width: 55,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: FlutterSwitch(
                activeColor: AppColor.homePageThemeColor,
                height: 28,
                padding: 3,
                value: value,
                onToggle: (val) {
                  var call = callback(val);
                  print(call);
                  setState(() {
                    print('help');
                    value = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

I was used to text, switch's initial value and callback function in the widget. It is working fine but how do we reload the widget when the other widget value is changed?

**widget using**

```
return Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: SwitchField(
                            title: data['title'],
                            value: overTurning,
                            callback: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                partAStateValues[index]['data'] = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        );
```

**My state value change function**

```
if (calculationData['title'] == 'Misc Vehicles') {
      if (value == 'All Others') {
        setState(() {
          overTurning = true;
          partAStateValues[partAStateValues.length - 1]['data'] = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          overTurning = false;

          partAStateValues[partAStateValues.length - 1]['data'] = false;
        });
      }
    }
```

The `overTurning` state value is changed but the switch doesn't change

What should I do?.. Help me

Comment: Can you include a sample full widget for the use case that will reproduce the error,

Comment: Try to print the value variabe inside your build method. It may didn't change

Comment: added my example gif

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is `Uniquekey()`

kindly reference this blog [Click here](https://jelenaaa.medium.com/how-to-force-widget-to-redraw-in-flutter-2eec703bc024)